# Is there a way to remove rows permanently in R data frames?

Tags: r

I'm searching for a function that I can remove rows permanently from an R data frame.
For example:

```
> df<-data.frame(AA=LETTERS[1:5],
           NN=c(NA, 12, 21, NA, 11))
> df
#  AA NN
#1  A NA
#2  B 12
#3  C 21
#4  D NA
#5  E 11
```

When I use complete.cases, R just drops the rows from the data frame (df) not creating a new df with new levels and row names, as observed below:

```
> df<-df[complete.cases(df),]
> df
#  AA NN
#2  B 12
#3  C 21
#5  E 11
> levels(df$AA)
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

What I want is the following df:

```
>df
#  AA NN
#1  B 12
#2  C 21
#3  E 11
> levels(df$AA)
#[1] "B" "C" "E"
```

Is there a way to do this in R?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can wrap with `droplevels` to remove the unused `levels` after subsetting

```
df <- droplevels(df[complete.cases(df),])
levels(df$AA)
#[1] "B" "C" "E"
row.names(df) <- NULL
```